# Error uploading file with Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans

I am facing a problem while uploading a file through a java Servlet. I am using netBeans

```
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

     //(...)
     DiskFileItemFactory  factory = new DiskFileItemFactory(); 
     factory.setSizeThreshold (maxMemSize); 
     factory.setRepository (new File ("/ home /")); 
     ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload (factory); 
     upload.setSizeMax(maxFileSize);
     List fileItems = upload.parseRequest (request); //here it gives the error
  //data processing
}
```

`Says:
incompatible types: HttpServletRequest cannot be converted to RequestContext.`
Exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest

Even if I cast it into `Requestcontext` , still it doesn't work
But if I do the parsing context to get the following error:
java.lang.ClassCastException: can not be cast to org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.RequestContext

Thank you for your attention

Comment: edited the post,  added information.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but looking over some old code I had for uploading a file, I know I had to get a ServletContext object.

Got this with

ServletContext sc = request.getSession().getServletContext()

Might be a version for RequestContext or it may be possible to case.

Comment: Can you post the actual stack?

Comment: I have to import some .jar or libraries  to run this type of code?

Comment: when I wrote the code in netbeans import some libraries, thought it was necessary, but it seems no 
Now do import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem, and gives error. 
Know how to care for my project this librarie?